# Run shell builtin/script command from Deno

Tags: deno

I sometimes need to execute a built-in shell command like [`type`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/type.1p.html), or just run an arbitrary shell command string (as a single string rather than an array of command + arguments). While I prefer the API of `Deno.run` for the vast majority of cases, it doesn't let me do either of these.

Is there any clean way to do these in Deno? It doesn't need to be the same solution for both, but it could be. I'm currently using a solution like what's seen [here](https://deno.land/x/drake@v1.5.0/lib/utils.ts#L213), but it doesn't feel very elegant, and I'd love to find a better way. Another alternative I considered was writing the command to a temp file with `.sh`/`.ps1` extension and then running that.

Comment: The solution you are currently using (the one you linked to) is the idiomatic method. If it doesn’t feel elegant to you, then just wrap it in a function with arguments that feel better to use. Also, note that [the current subprocess API will soon be replaced and deprecated](https://deno.com/blog/v1.21#new-unstable-api-for-subprocesses).

Comment: Thanks for the validation! And that new API sounds much more friendly! I didn't see anything about having unpiped output that inherits the parent's stdout/stderr and streams there, but I assume that will still be there.